# Where can I find out more about the Outlook 2007/Microsoft word html layout engine?

Tags: html, browser, layout, outlook-2007

I want to write an app that will render html using Outlook 2007/Microsoft Word 2007's html layout engine ...

I'm trying to do some research but keep coming up empty unlike with the IE HTML layout engine, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)

I just want a code name, dll location, a point in the right direction ... something ...
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the MS Word OLE component. You can basically embed Word in your application using OLE and there should be a lot of OLE documentation on MSDN.

Examples using VBA: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237337
MS Office Developer Portal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office